# Need help creating / using a collection within a class (C#, ASP.Net, MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, enums

I'm trying to create a small web app that allows movies to be stored in a database. I have this `Movie` class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
    public List<string> Actors { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string MoviePic { get; set; } // path to image
    public int RunningTime { get; set; } // in minutes
    public string Trailer { get; set; } // youtube url
}
```

In my controller, I'm trying to create a movie using that class:

```
var jurassicPark = new Movie
{
    Title = "Jurassic Park",
    Synopsis = "Dinosaurs go crazy on an island.",
    MoviePic = "jurassicLogo.jpg"
};
```

All of this works great, but I also want to add a `Rating` property, which can *only* be one of four strings representing an image of that rating sign. In other words, I don't want to just have a `public string Rating` property that can be any old string. I want to only have the choice between the four specific strings.

For example, I originally put this in the Movie class:

```
public class Rating
{
    public string GRating = "g.jpg";
    public string PgRating = "pg.jpg";
    public string Pg13Rating = "pg13.jpg";
    public string RRating = "r.jpg";
}
```

That didn't work, so I did some googling and tried this instead:

```
public enum Rating
{
    GRated = "G.jpg",
    PgRated = "PG.jpg",
    Pg13Rated = "PG13.jpg",
    RRated = "R.jpg"
}
```

That didn't work, either. I could call `Movie.Rating.GRated` in my controller, but I couldn't actually assign a rating to a movie. I tried adding `public Rating Rating { get; set; }` to the Movie Class, which seemed like it might allow me to add a Rating to my `jurassicPark` object in the controller, but it didn't like anything I tried (ex: `Rating = Movie.Rating.Pg13Rated` gave me a red squiggly).

It seems like this should be super simple, but I'm still somewhat new to ASP.Net and I'm having a lot of trouble with this one.

Comment: I did try that, but I couldn't figure out how to assign a Rating (see bottom paragraph)

Comment: I mention trying that in the bottom paragraph

Comment: An `enum` is the correct choice is you know they will never change - but enums must be integral types (except `char`) - typically `int` but can be `byte`, `long` etc. The value cannot be a `string`.  If you want to display `Rating.GRated` as "g.jpg", then use a `[Display]` attribute

Comment: Do consider that there are multiple rating systems used in multiple countries and that movies can be re-rated (after editing, appeal or events). While you might not want to implement such a complex model at first, it may influence how you choose to implement a model that is currently simpler. For example, @Shyju's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827112/2226988). (There are competing patterns and anti-patterns here.)

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, The better solution is to create a separate lookup table to store the possible list of Ratings and have a foreign key in your movie table. On the database level this ensure that you are storing only one of those values(**Referential integrity**) even if your code fails to set the correct value

You can add additional properties to this lookup table. For example, a logo image for each rating, description for each rating etc.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id {set;get;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
    public List<string> Actors { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string MoviePic { get; set; } // path to image
    public int RunningTime { get; set; } // in minutes
    public string Trailer { get; set; } // youtube url

    public int RatingId {set;get;}
    public Rating Rating { set;get;} 
}
public class Rating
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Name {set;get;} ;
   public string Description {set;get;} ;
   public string LogoImageUrl {set;get;} ;
}
```

having said that, you can simply use an enum and store the string. but the above approach of a lookup table allows you to keep the additional properties for each rating items.